# Is it possible for `topmost.__init__.py` to access global variables in `topmost.submodule.__init__.py`?

Tags: python, inheritance, global-variables, modularity

If my Python library `topmost` is structured as such:

```
topmost
    /__init__.py
    /submodule
      /__init__.py
```

**Is it possible for `topmost.__init__.py` to access global variables in `topmost.submodule.__init__.py`?**

With the `topmost.submodule.__init__.py`, there should be some global variables:

```
def characterize(input):
    global abc 
    abc = load_abc_model()
    return abc.func(input)
```

I've tried this in `topmost.__init__.py` but the global variables in `topmost.submodule.__init__.py` is still not accessible:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from topmost import submodule

__import__('submodule', globals())
```

But only the `abc` global variable isn't accessible on the topmost.

Comment: You will have to define the variable in the modules namespace as well, not only inside the function.

Comment: The global variable declared/defined (solely) through/within a function will appear when the function is first executed.

Comment: For some reason the `global` in Python is poorly understood by beginners. Perhaps they expect it to work exactly like some other language they know?

Comment: @Leon, is that true that the global will appear when the function is first executed? I thought the global scope won't be getting out of the module, unless explicitly imported by the topmost module.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy some other language being C-ish? ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A global variable declared/defined through/within a function will appear (in the global scope) when the function is first executed.

Proof:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 'abc' in globals()
False
>>> def foo():
...     global abc
...     abc = 123
...     print('foo')
... 
>>> 'abc' in globals()
False
>>> foo()
foo
>>> 'abc' in globals()
True
>>>
```

---

With the current setup:

```
topmost
    /__init__.py
    /submodule
      /__init__.py
```

and:

```
def characterize(input):
    global abc 
    abc = load_abc_model()
    return abc.func(input)
```

`topmost.submodule.abc` will **go live only after** `topmost.submodule.characterize()` is called.

Comment: That's because it's not in a submodule ;P

Comment: The same will hold true for a submodule

Comment: I couldn't replicate the same behavior in the submodule: https://gist.github.com/alvations/507f3d85552b7db0423998eac26ecdea =)

Comment: I'm getting a little confused, but the `_nltk_downloader` is still unaccessible after `earthy.download()`, right?

Comment: It is in the module's own "global" scope. Check that `earthy._nltk_downloader` exists: `'_nltk_downloader' in dir(earthy)`.

Comment: I didn't look at the `earthy`'s code with enough attention. Since the `download()` function belongs to the `earthy.nltk_wrappers` submodule, you should look for the "global" variable `_nltk_downloader` in that submodule: `'_nltk_downloader' in dir(earthy.nltk_wrappers)`

Comment: Ah ha, yes, the `_nltk_downloader` is in `earthy.nltk_wrappers`. So to generalize and going back to the question, to propagate the global variables in submodule to topmost, `__import__('submodule', globals())` needs to be called after calling all the `characterize()`?

Comment: Frankly, it's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve with `__import__('submodule', globals())`

Comment: It's a dirty hack to let `topmost` access variables in `submodule` but I think I'm abusing it.

Comment: With current setup, `topmost.submodule.abc` will go live only after `topmost.submodule.characterize()` is called.